# Asserting value for read-only field using Selenium webdriver C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit, assert

I am using Selenium webdriver with NUnit framework and I can't get around to Assert a read-only text field on a html form. Selenium is able to find the element by 'Id' but unable to read the text within the element and is returning a blank string, and my assertion fails.

Below is the block of code on the application -

```
<td nowrap="" colspan="2">
<input readonly="" tabindex="-1" class="readonly" type="text" 
onfocus="gcurrObj=this;JS_FieldFocus(this, 'frmDetails')" 
onchange="JS_FieldChange(this, 'frmDetails')" id="txtAccountName" 
name="undefined" value="James Bond" size="60" 
style=""></td>
```

I am using the following code to read, but selenium is returning a blank string

```
var AccName = driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtAccountName"));
Assert.That(AccName.Text.Contains("James"));
```

Any help is appreciated..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text in the text fields is not part of the `WebElement`, you can't get it with the `Text` property. To get it you need to use the `value` attribute

```
Assert.That(AccName.GetAttribute("value").Contains("James"));
```

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple reasons behind a blank `string` being returned. You can take help of a `Locator Strategy` that identifies the element uniquely and then use `Assert` as follows :

```
var AccName = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@class='readonly' and @id='txtAccountName']")).GetAttribute("value");
Assert.That(AccName.Contains("James"));
```